# How to create fastest searching (filtering data) field in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, elasticsearch

I need to create User selection page for my web based application (User searching page), I have millions of registered users in my database and I want to search that users by typing the name in the text field.And by the way it should be suggest the name of users when i am typing the letters on the field (Like jquery tables).

- I am using .net MVC3 for develop my web application
- I am using Amazon database server for store my data (Amazon S3)
- Millions of people will access this site.

-- I have tried to come up solution with elasticSearch I think this is well suited for document text search.

I want to know the way of, how can i speed up searching result? Is there any techniques to speed up filtering data from Database? Can I use ElasticSearch for this?

Please anybody can give me a best solution/ suggestions for come up with this problem?
If you can give me a examples it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no much tecniques on this:

1. Use AJAX to query the subset of users
2. On server side, one time request was got, get first (say) 10 elements of the subset found and send it to the user
3. On client side use defered scrolling: the control that shows the list of users do not show all users od subset got from the server, but only set of them. When user scrolls down/up list refreshes by querying again the server. Say on list view it's possible to see 10 users at a time, you get from server 15, so on scrolling at least next 5 will appear immediately.

Something like this.

Comment: What about the elastic search?

Comment: @FazalMohamed: what do you mean ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/SvcIntro.html here is the link about Elasticsearch

Comment: @FazalMohamed: this is a Amazon's query engine. I don't know if it supports paging of data.